# Make waiting thread skip the rest of the wait/continue

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, interrupt

I have a scenario where I have one thread that loops between waiting and executing a task. However, I would like to interrupt the wait for the thread (skip the rest of the wait if you will) and continue on to doing the task.

Anyone have any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: are you using wait with a timeout ? or are you using wait and notify ?

Comment: I am using wait with a timeout.

Comment: Do you mean you would like the thread to stop waiting when something comes along for it to do?  You might be better with an appropriately configured ExecutorService for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Thread.interrupt is for:

```
import java.util.Date;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(new Date());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep for 10 seconds.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Sleep interrupted");
                }
                System.out.println(new Date());
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); // sleep for 2 seconds.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        t1.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Thread t1 will only sleep for 2 seconds, since the main thread interrupts it.  Keep in mind that this will interrupt many blocking operations such as IO.

Comment: Yup. Thread.interrupt() will interrupt wait() (all variations), sleep(), as well as all blocking IO. Interrupt is usually used when you want to discard whatever the thread was doing. If, however, you want to wait for something in particular to happen, you should use wait()/notify(). Read about them in the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is implement wait()/notify() ! check it out this tutorial: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306

There are a lot of them out there! if you need a more specific case, post a bit of your code!

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wait()` and `notify()`. If your thread is waiting, you'll need to resume it by calling `notify()` from a different thread.